# react-native how to execute a function in everytime when I tap in the view

Tags: javascript, react-native

first.sorry for my poor english. I'm trying to set a login dialog when I tap in the profile page. I used `react-navigation` for the tabbar.

if I execute the function in `componentDidMount`. it just execute once. I back to the main page then tap the profile page again. it won't execute again.

> componentDidMount() {
>       this._bootstrapAsync();  }

what is the solution that I can execute the function in everytime I tab in the view? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below link. this will have answer for your question.

[Handle Tab changes in React Navigation v2](https://itnext.io/handle-tab-changes-in-react-navigation-v2-faeadc2f2ffe)

[React Navigation V3 Tab changes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress)